# how to set new colors to dynamically added bar in angular bar chart

Tags: angular, charts, bar-chart, ng2-charts

Below is my chart sample

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-barchart-example-jodddf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbarchart%2Fbarchart.ts

when clicking `change data` button - i am adding new bar to chart, want to change that newly added bar color only.

Is there any possibilities to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public randomize(): void {
let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.barChartData));
clone[0].data = [55, 60, 75, 100];
clone[1].data = [58, 55, 60, 100];

this.barChartColors[0].backgroundColor = [
  'rgba(105,159,177,0.2)',
  'rgba(105,159,177,0.2)',
  'rgba(105,159,177,0.2)',
  'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
];

this.barChartColors[1].backgroundColor = [
  'rgba(77,20,96,0.3)',
  'rgba(77,20,96,0.3)',
  'rgba(77,20,96,0.3)',
  'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)',
];
this.barChartColors = [...this.barChartColors];

setTimeout(() => {
  this.barChartData = clone;
}, 100);
```

}

Comment: Thanks @zainhassan, working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-barchart-example-5efpsy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbarchart%2Fbarchart.ts